# How to call function inside web page From Web User Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have WUC inside a web page. I want to call a function in this web page BUT from WUC?

For more details:
My web page called "**pg_reportThreats**" that has function named "**fn_bindAccordion**();" and i have UserControl named "**WUC_CommentsAndReplies**" what i want is to call  function "fn_bindAccordion()" from my page "pg_reportThreats"..

Comment: Show some little code sample !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is technically possible to access the web page from the [Control.Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.page(v=vs.110).aspx) property. You can then cast this Page to the correct type, eg:

```
var myPage = this.Page as pg_reportThreats;
myPage.doSomething();
```

However, it is typically not 'good design' for a control to depend on the page.
The idea with a UserControl is that it's a reusable component, like a button.
When you click the button, it does not call the page and ask it to do something. The button class gives you access to the OnClick event, so that the Page can listen to that event (if it wants to) and do something on it's own.
You can read more about User Controls in the articles [ASP.NET User Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx) 
and [Events in UserControls](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/user-controls/events/)

Comment: When i used your above code...  
var myPage = this.Page as pg_reportThreats;
            myPage.fn_bindAccordion();

Comment: this code got an error: "pg_reportThreats" could not be found or missing directory!!

Comment: It is very possible that this is the case. When your Page depends on your Control, and your Control depends on your Page, which of the 2 do you compile first? This is called a Circular Reference/Circular Dependency, and is one of the reasons it is not good design to use this approach. I think in your case you will need to use the solution with a custom event. The Events in UserControls article I linked to should help you get started with that.

Comment: Thanks  Christiaan Rakowski you are right.i solved the problem with another thinking...thanks